# Lightning aura date field issue is there in ios , ipad etc

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

i am trying to give date field of Birth date or Order date whatever date we want i am able to do and control functioning from lightning aura component for android like text field width, padding etc..
But for Date field type like type = "Date" , the width is not working as expecting in ios, ipad..
Basically Lightning alignnment for Date field in ios, ipad not working...
Please resolve this issue..

Ss of andoid and IPhone i have attached you can see width difference of same code in lightning aura..

[image: Android Date Field]

[image: Ios Date Field]

i am expecting as i am getting output in android same i want to get in ios, ipad also..
Please provide soln as soon as possible..

Answer (score 0):

1. While Lightning Aura components follow ES5 syntax and are sometimes not responsive
2. You would often come across such things when displaying Aura Components in Salesforce Mobile App
3. If you know that your feature would be used in Salesforce Mobile App as well then i suggest you to implement it in LWC
4. Since LWC components are meant to be more mobile friendly than the Aura Components

Comment: Thank you for you response.. i will try to do with LWC..